# how to correct my code to print on different sheets of an excel document

Tags: php, html, excel

I hope you can help me, I have a code which prints me dynamically with a while on a sheet of text 3 tables, but I would like for each iteration, that is, each table is printed on different excel sheets, this is my code:

```
<?php

$serverName = "xxx"; 
$dbname = "xxx";
$dbuser = "Xxx";
$dbpassword = "XXX";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$dbname, "UID"=>$dbuser, "PWD"=>$dbpassword);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);


header("Content-Type: application/xls"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Estrucuturas-".$ts.".xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

$sql="select id,number,name from documents";

 $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
 if( $stmt === false) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
 }
?>

//3 tables: 
<?php
while( $key = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {   
?>
<table>
<tr><td>id</td><td colspan="2"><?php echo $id=$key[0];?></td></tr>
<tr><td>number</td><td colspan="2"><?php echo $num=$key[1];?></td></tr>
<tr><td>name</td><td colspan="2"><?php echo $nam=$key[2];?></td></tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Not sure this is a sql server question.

Comment: AFAIK there is no direct solution. But it is not that hard to create regular xlsx from within php.